# Base line of Mathematics operator in TextView?

Tags: android, math, textview, baseline

I have to draw mathematical equations like `x - (20 * x)/100` in TextView and it has to seems like this:

[image]

I use `ReplacementSpan` to add fraction on the baseline of TextView.But it seems that mathematical operators do not aligned respect to the base line of TextView.So result is like this:

[image]

Now I want to know how I can find the baseline of mathematical operator to align the fraction with respect to it?

[image]

Comment: what is "baseline of mathematical operation" ?

Comment: @pskink Excuse me,I mean "baseline of mathematical operation".I add a picture to my question.Please see it,thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
Paint.getTextBounds with "-" text
```

Comment: OK!That is very good.I had asked another question "http://stackoverflow.com/q/22031379/1043882". Do you have any idea in about it?